# Need help understanding XOR cipher

Tags: c++, arm

I am trying to modify a save file for a game.  I think it is using an XOR cipher to encrypt it.  Looking though the disassembly I think I found the function that decrypts it.  I ran the assembly through a decompiler to get a better grip on what is going on.

I am a C# programmer with some knowledge of C/C++.  I generally understand what is accomplished by this code, but there are some details I don't understand.

```
int __fastcall DecryptBuffer(unsigned __int8 *a1, int a2, int a3, unsigned int a4, int a5)
{
  unsigned __int8 *v5;
  unsigned __int8 *v6;
  int result;
  int v8;

  v5 = a1;
  v6 = &a1[a2];
  result = a5;
  v8 = a5 - (_DWORD)v5;
  while ( v5 != v6 )
  {
    result = *v5 ^ *(unsigned __int8 *)(a3 + (unsigned int)&v5[v8] % a4);
    *v5++ = result;
  }
  return result;
}
```

It accepts as parameters:

- `a1` - a byte array
- `a2` - the length of the array
- `a3` - `0xB19D425B`
- `a4` - `0x107`
- `a5` - `0x00`

First, I can't figure out the value of `v8`.  I don't know what `(_DWORD)v5` means, or why it is subtracted from zero.

Second, I don't know what `(unsigned int)&v5[v8]` is actually doing.  I take it to mean it is looking up a byte somewhere in the array, but is it retrieving a single byte and casting to an uint, or four bytes?

Here is the disassembly:

```
sub_301E44
PUSH.W          {R4-R8,LR}
MOV             R4, R0
ADDS            R6, R0, R1
LDR             R0, [SP,#0x18+arg_0]
MOV             R7, R2
MOV             R8, R3
SUBS            R5, R0, R4
loc_301E54
CMP             R4, R6
BEQ             locret_301E6C
ADDS            R0, R5, R4
MOV             R1, R8
BL.W            __aeabi_uidivmod
LDRB            R0, [R4]
LDRB            R3, [R7,R1]
EORS            R0, R3
STRB.W          R0, [R4],#1
B               loc_301E54
locret_301E6C
POP.W           {R4-R8,PC}
```

This is the function that calls the above:

```
PUSH            {R0-R2,LR}
MOVS            R3, #0
LDR             R2, =(dword_8749EF - 0x301E80)
STR             R3, [SP,#0x10+var_10]
MOVW            R3, #0x107
ADD             R2, PC  ; dword_8749EF
BL              sub_301E44
ADD             SP, SP, #0xC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(_DWORD)v5` is simply casting the `__int8*` pointer to `_DWORD`. Decompilations tend to be quite messy if you don't fix variable types, so let's ignore types for a moment.

To understand the value of v8, substitute it into the expression bellow: 
`&v5[a5 - v5_old]`. We can also understand this as `v5 + a5 - v5_old`. `v5` is being incremented with each iteration of the loop, so the above expression is basically the current index plus `a5`.

The current index plus `a5` modulo `a4` (presumably the length of the buffer pointed to by `a3`) is then added to `a3` and the corresponding byte is XOR'd to the byte currently pointed to by `v5`.

Here's my take on the algorithm:

```
void DecryptBuffer ( char *buffer, int buffer_len, char *key, int key_len, int key_start )
{ 
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < buffer_len; i++ )
        buffer [ i ] ^= key [ ( key_start + i ) % key_len ];
}
```

Or in other words, XOR with the key repeating over and over.

This is quite standard, so it's probably right, but it could be wrong—as I said, the decompilation is quite messy. If you want a sure answer, either clean it up by fixing variable types or post the disassembly as well.

Comment: Thanks so much, that works.  I would never have realized that `key` was a pointer to an array (rather than just an integer) and that `v8` was being used to determine how far into the buffer we were.  I attached the disassembly for completeness.